# R: Warning when building a package

Tags: r, package

In the package I'm writing, I have a "custom" print function for objects of class, say, "myclass".

```
print.myclass <- { 
  # ... 
  # ...
}
```

In the print.myclass.Rd file, I have something like this:

```
\name{print.myclass}
\alias{print.myclass}
\alias{print}
\title{Print method for objects of class \code{myclass}.}
\description{Display \code{myclass} objects in the console or in \emph{RStudio's Viewer}.}
\usage{
  \method{print}{myclass}(x, method, \dots)
  print(x, method="some.method", ...)
}
```

When I run the R CMD check --as-cran, I get the following warning:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING Functions or methods
with usage in documentation object 'print.summarytools' but not in code:   
print
```

I must have tried all the possible combinations of trial and error, importing this and erasing that, but I'm hiting a wall. I'm not even sure what "but not in code" means... Are we talking about the R code in the R scripts, or the code in the .Rd file?

I'm hoping someone who's had enough experience building packages could guide me towards the light.

Thx

Comment: Yes, I read _with usage in documentation ... but not in code_ as suggesting that you have the `.Rd` side covered, but an issue on the `.R` side.

Comment: take out `\alias{print}` ??  I think "but not in code" means "but the [relevant function is not defined anywhere in the package's R] code"

Comment: It suggest to me that somewhere in your `.Rd` files you invoke the method `print.summarytools` but it's not defined in your package. So far as I can tell it's not part of the `base` install collection of `print` methods, so the cran-checker can't find it.

Comment: Trying to remove the `\alias{print}` generated a new warning (oh how I like tose) that actually led me to the culprit. `Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object [...]`. So I went back to my `\usage` section; its 2nd line was the culprit. So the "_code_" apparently referred to the \usage secction. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to remove the 2nd line in the \usage section:

```
\usage{
  \method{print}{myclass}(x, method, \dots)
  print(x, method="some.method", ...)        <- culprit
}
```

To keep the additionnal bit of information given in the second line (the default value for `method`, this works:

```
\usage{
  \method{print}{myclass}(x, method="some.method", \dots)
}
```